# 1118578 issue in my android app facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

My facebook login my application is work fine before some hours,but suddenly it shows a error like ,

> Login failed. Please contact the maker of this app and ask them to
>   report issue #1118578 to Facebook.

now i am not able to login my  application,why this happen?please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284709068314243).

In that facebook authority said this :

**"Thanks for the report. We do not support android:launchMode="singleInstance" due to technical reasons, and the new SDK throws a diagnostic message that should notify you when you try to login."**

Comment: @user2198738 check my answer and notify me whether this helps you or not.

Comment: actually i am not using this in my manifest file android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: then what is the reason for this issue? help me.

Comment: in my manifest file i am not use this android:launchMode="singleInstance",and some device it working well.but in samsung galaxy s2 it is not working,i check my manifest file and i am sure that am not using this line.